# MSDeploy: error using runCommand provider to call remote .cmd file (timeout)

Tags: command-line, timeout, msdeploy

We are running into an error when trying to use the MSDeploy "runCommand" provider to execute a .cmd file on a remote machine. The expected run time should be about 10 seconds, but MSDeploy only runs it for about 2-3 seconds, after which time error details are returned.

Here is the complete MSDeploy "runCommand" command line text I am using:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:runCommand="D:\web deploy tester\test_cmd.cmd",dontUseCommandExe=false,waitAttempts=5,waitInterval=1000 -dest:auto,computername=http://test-machine:89/MsDeployAgentService/,userName=aaa,password=bbb
```

Here are the error details returned:

```
Error 'Error: (4/21/2010 12:19:25 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: The process 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' (command line '/c "D:\web deploy tester\test_cmd.cmd"') was terminated because it exceeded the wait time.
Error count: 1.
' occurred in call to RunCommand
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: I have the same problem, regardless of the waitInterval i specify, msdeploy immediately returns this error, when it clearly hasnt waited for the specified time before erroring.

Comment: I noticed that when I used this in a batch file and I was using `&quot;` I made the mistake of including the `waitInterval` inside the quote for the command path rather than outside it: `..&quot;,waitInterval..`

Answer (score 6):

You should specify a higher value of waitInterval. This value is in milliseconds. You might want to try 20000 (20 seconds). The default value is 1000.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Sayed. I have tried your suggestion and have even given the process up to a few minutes to complete, but this does not resolve the issue. 

Also, according to the runCommand documentation, it appears the setting you mentioned is the length of the interval between retries, not the time allowed for the remote command to complete its execution before timing-out.

The .cmd can be run from the command prompt on the local machine without any problem and the account running the operation has admin-level privileges. Any other theories as to why this is occurring?

Comment: Hate to say it, but "me too".  I have a "runCommand" in my SourceManifest.xml, and waitInterval/waitAttempts appear to be ignored

Comment: I managed to get MsDeploy.exe to do something else other than default by setting waitAttempts=1 and waitInterval=20000, but it's not what I expected and have given up on the runCommand provider

Comment: Trying to specify it through the the manifest doesn't seem to do anything.  Same if I crack open the zip file and add the attributes in archive.xml.

Comment: I thought I remember adding a follow up to my last comment... Anyhow, never mind what I said.  I just wasn't updating my packages correctly.  When in doubt, do a full build clean, blow away the obj directory, and completely rebuild and repackage.  Seems some options don't get updated if you don't do this.